# cannot boot in normal mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot

On my laptop Dell G3 15 I am running a dual boot, ubuntu 20.04 alongside with Windows 10. Windows works fine if the SATA operation is on RAID on and secure boot is enabled.
however, Ubuntu (with SATA operation is on AHCI and secure boot is disabled) when I try to boot in normal mode, the system is freezing and gets stuck on the boot screen and the Ubuntu logo starts flickering. This goes on forever. however, I can boot using recovery mode!!!
I tried to reinstall my ubuntu using live USB, but either cannot boot the install mode or it is freeze after boot and starts the installation!!
How can I solve this problem!!!

the BIOS version is 1.8.0

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Press Esc while it's flickering and see if yo notice messages that point to the problem. Also, do you have a dedicated GPU (Nvidia, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information, but my instincts say this is probably caused by [Secure Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/116569/htg-explains-how-windows-8s-secure-boot-feature-works-what-it-means-for-linux/). Basically, Secure Boot incorrectly identifies Ubuntu as malware and prevents it from booting. You can disable this by entering your BIOS settings and setting Boot Mode (sometimes "UEFI Mode") to Legacy Boot instead, and then rebooting. If you want to use the Secure Boot feature (not my recommendation), then you can try booting to Ubuntu in recovery mode and install the Microsoft signed bootloader:

```
sudo apt install shim-signed
```

Which should allow Secure Boot to trust your Ubuntu install. If neither of those solve the problem, can you update your original post with model your device is, BIOS, Windows and Ubuntu version?

Comment: Many thanks, I did update my original post